# Jhessian Thief and Aqueous Form

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Jhessian Thief](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jhessian%20Thief) enchanted with an [Aqueous Form](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aqueous%20Form), and it deals damage to my opponent, do I get to Scry 1 before or after I draw a card from [Jhessian Thief](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jhessian%20Thief)'s ability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Aqueous Form](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aqueous%20Form)'s scry ability triggers when the creature attacks. [Jhessian Thief](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jhessian%20Thief)'s draw ability triggers when it deals combat damage to a player. Thus Aqueous Form's ability will trigger and resolve in the declare attackers step. Jhessian Thief's ability won't trigger until later, in the combat damage step.